# Prolog List instantiation

Tags: list, prolog

i want to create a predifined list. But i am doing something wrong because when i pass it as an argument it doesnt work.
Here is the code i have:

```
list([5, 1, 2, 8, 10, 4, 3, 6, 9, 7]).

print( [ ] ).
print( [ X | Y ] ):- write(X), write(' '), print( Y ).

test:- print(list).
```

Console output:

```
1 ?- a.
true .
```

It doesnt work. But here is when i pass the list myself:

```
2 ?- print([5, 1, 2, 8, 10, 4, 3, 6, 9, 7]).
5 1 2 8 10 4 3 6 9 7 
true.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use variables to communicate information between predicates. Your `list` predicate doesn't "return" value, it instantiates a variable.

```
test :- list(L), print(L).
```